# How to solve this Laravel Error (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, migration

I want to create foreign key on my migrate but it shows this error when I run 
"php artisan migrate" command -

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lr_agnes`.`#sql-2e8c_93` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `prices` add constraint `prices_condition_id_foreign` foreign key (`condition_id`) references `conditions` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

I already tried this things - 
1. Drop all table from database including migration table.then I run "php artisan migrate"
2. Run "php artisan migrate:reset"
3. Run "php artisan migrate:refresh"
4. Run "php artisan migrate:fresh"
There's no options didn't work. I tried to solve the problem by these things.

My Migration File Code -

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->integer('condition_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('condition_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('conditions')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

when I run "`php artisan migrate`" Every time I got this error -

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lr_agnes`.`#sql-2e8c_93` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQ
L: alter table `prices` add constraint `prices_condition_id_foreign` foreign key (`condition_id`) references `conditions` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please try: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('condition_id');`

Comment: @dparoli Thank you try and let you know